# Transparent background for actionbar without overlay?

Tags: java, android

I am able to create a complete transparent actionbar using the following in the styles.xml

```
  <!-- makes the action bar not take screen space , by appearing as an overlay. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

and doing the following in the code

```
mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

The net effect is an action bar that is completely transparent , set as an overlay. I want the actionbar not to be displayed as an overlay , rather take up some screen space. I naturally proceed as follows.

```
      <!-- makes the action bar not take screen space , by appearing as an overlay. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
```

I get the following
[image: ActionbarScreenshot]

What is this light grey color , and why has the setbackgrounddrawable stopped working when I set the actionbaroverlay to false ? .

Thanks .

EDIT :

My default styles.xml has the following

```
  -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.



    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- removes the shadow underneath the actionbar -->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <!-- changes the overflow icon -->
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/slide_icon</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the `ActionBar` transparent unless you set `windowActionBarOverlay` to `true`. I assume by "take up some screen space" you mean you want to account for the height of the ActionBar in your layouts. You can either set:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

to pad the top of the layout with the height of the ActionBar, **or** set

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

in your active style. This will enforce all layouts to fit underneath the ActionBar in this case.

Comment: I mean exactly that. I do want the space the actionbar takes to be an area where the layouts shouldn't be drawn. In what style can i use the fitssystemwindows attribute?

Comment: You can use it in your applications overall theme, or you can apply it directly to the root view of any layout.

Comment: the margintop technique also introduced the same grey area in place of the actionbar . I believe i will look into fitssystemwindows

Comment: I am afraid the fitssystemwindows also didn't create a difference. I still see that grey area up there.

Comment: What color is the actual background of the Activity? Unless you are setting one explicitly, it's going to default to the one specificed by your theme.

Comment: Jeff I have an image as a background of my Activity :(